# Play framework manually opened Hibernate session doesn't persist

Tags: hibernate, session, playframework, persistence

I'm creating a second session beside the one automatically created by the play! framework and I want to change just one field of a specific object. For some reason it won't persist.
If I get the Object again in the same session the field is changed but after the request it's back to it's original value.

Here's some code:

```
Session session = (Session) JPA.em().getDelegate();
    Session s = session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS); //been playing around with these 
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();

    // Get Object
    org.hibernate.Query query = s.createQuery("SELECT c From Course c WHERE c.id=:id").setLong("id", 100);
    List<Course> courses = query.list();
    Course course = courses.get(0);

    course.title = "test";

    // s.save(course);
    // s.update(course); Tried all of them
    // s.persist(course);
    s.saveOrUpdate(course);

    // s.flush();
    t.commit();
    s.flush();
```

Help much appreciated.